# Migrating from ubuntu 12.04 to 18.04 iptables export error

Tags: iptables

I have an old 12.04 server with these iptables rules:

```
Chain NAME (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:discard /* someservice */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:port /* someservices */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  private-ip           anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  private-ip           anywhere             tcp dpt:service /* service server */

Chain NAME2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:port
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:tftp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain OTHERNAME (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  public-ip            anywhere            
DROP       all  --  public-ip            anywhere            
DROP       all  --  public-ip            anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

This is just an example, there are a lot more of rules. I tried to migrate the server by booting up a new 18.04 VM. I was able to transfer everything correctly except the iptables. When I do 
'''
iptables-restore < iptables-export
'''
I get "line 46 failed" It's just a random line with a rule, I remove it and then it will fail at the next line, nothing works.

I tried entering the command manually from the export file but I get:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
or
iptables v1.6.1: Couldn't load target `OTHERNAME':No such file or directory
```

I did add those chain names on the new server. The old iptables version is 1.4.12. I also tried iptables-converter but that didn't do anything.

If in the end I can't possibly add those iptables rules, how would the rules look like with ufw command?

Comment: I also get this error: `iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just rebooted the VM so it upgraded the kernel and now the iptable-restore worked. Thank you all.